# JQuery Text animation - How to replace current text values with new ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery fly-in text animator applied to a div. Now the div can only be a certain size and thus allows a certain amount of lines of text. Now I would like to add more lines of text to the animation, basically replacing the current ones, and looping back to the first text lines again. Check my code to see what I mean:

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.flying1 .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
    $('.flying1 .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "0px"}, 1500); //animate first text
    var int = setInterval(changeText, 2000);    // call changeText function every 5 seconds

function changeText(){  
    var $activeText = $(".flying1 .active-text");     //get current text    
    var $nextText = $activeText.next();  //get next text
    /*if($activeText.next().length == 0) $nextText = $('.container .flying-text:first');

    $activeText.animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    $activeText.animate({marginLeft: "-100px"});*/

     if ($activeText.next().length == 0) {
        $nextText = $('.flying1 .flying-text:first'); //if it is last text, loop back to first text

        // To fade all out
        var $allText = $(".flying1 div");
        $allText .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $allText .animate({
            marginLeft: "-100px"
        });
    }

    $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "0px"}, 1500, function(){

        $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                           
    });
}
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flying1">
  <div class="flying-text active-text">Text1</div>                  
  <div class="flying-text">Text2</div>                      
  <div class="flying-text">Text3</div>
  <div class="flying-text">Text4</div>
  <div class="flying-text">Text5</div>  
  <div class="flying-text">Text6</div>                   
</div>
```

That is the max amount of text that Div(.flying1) can take due to space constraints...
I want to add another 6 lines into that text animation that runs after Text1-6, so they would basically be Text7-12 running in the same space as Text1-6...

Thank You!!

Comment: why don't you count the total number of div using jquery in the changeText function and if current div is equal to total then set it to start again from the first one.

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstand your answer or if you don't understand my question...Currently I have 6 text lines in the animation, that loops back to number one once it gets to number 6. I want to add 6 more lines, but I do not have enough space vertically. So I want to dynamically replace text7 with text1, text8 with text2, text9 with text3...How do i do that?

Comment: when you reach to last div, just remove all the previous div and place this new div's. Use jQuery(".flying1").html(''); to remove all the previous div.

Comment: Cool thanks, but how to I loop back to the original text(Text1-6) once the new text(Text7-12) has finished animating?